# Dividir uma planilha em varias planilhas

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, vba, pandas, excel-vba

Tenho uma planilha com 5000 linhas que precisa ser dividida em planilhas com 790 linhas no maximo. Como posso fazer isso??

Comment: Essas são planilhas de dados pura? Se for, posso sugerir converter para `CSV` e tratar com `bash`/`shell script` numa resposta.

Comment: São planilhas com dados de importacoes, nada muito fora do padrão. Queria alguma solução em python se possivel

Comment: Ok, eu posso fornecer a ideia geral e a implementação em `bash`; estou com uma preguiça honesta de usar Python nesse momento, mas a transformação deve ser muito fácil

Comment: Ok....como seria em bash?

Comment: fiz a resposta em `bash` =) Creio que agora é a hora de marcar a resposta do Gabriel como a certa, a resposta que atendeu seu problema, já que a dele está em Python, se adequando melhor ao seu problema

Comment: Cara, obrigado pelo help e pelo bash tmb, ele vai ficar como alternativa ao python com certeza.

Answer (score 3):

Tente usar a função `readlines` para manipulação de arquivos:

```py
file = open('entrada.txt', 'r')
lines = file.readlines()
nfile = 0 # Numero para organizar os arquivos a serem criados, sera incrementado no loop for.
inicio = 0 # Inicio do trecho a ser escrito
fim = 0 # Fim do trecho
nlines = 790 # numero de linhas por arquivo 
rangeloop = len(lines)//nlines # numero de iterações a serem executadas no loop for
if len(lines) % nlines > 0: # Caso a conta nao dê exata, faz uma iteração a mais para escrever o que sobrou
    rangeloop += 1
for x in range(rangeloop):
    nfile += 1 
    fim += nlines
    arq = open("arq"+str(nfile)+".txt", 'w')
    arq.write(''.join(lines[inicio:fim]))
    inicio = fim
    arq.close()
```

Deu certo aqui, tente ai e me diga, qualquer duvida pode perguntar, está bem mal escrito porque fiz bem rapido.

Comment: Vou testar amigo!!!

Comment: Uma questão: Esse script vai fazer a divisão até que todas as 5000 linhas sejam distribuidas em varias planilhas??

Comment: O resultado será varios arquivos .txt com 790 linhas em cada, com exceção do ultimo que pode ter menos que 790

Comment: Não sei como são seus conhecimentos em Python, mas isso é um código bem mal formado, o correto seria vc fazer algumas alterações para permitir o usuário definir nome do arquivo de entrada, nome dos arquivos de saída, organizar aquelas declarações de variáveis, etc... Caso não saiba muito de Python, isso é muito simples, basta pesquisar no google que encontrará a resposta sem dificuldade.

Comment: Opa.....vou testar sim, qq coisa te falo. Obrigado!!!

Comment: Era por isso que eu não queria responder em Python. Sabia que tinha um [`import antigravity`](https://xkcd.com/353/) que fazia isso, só não sabia qual

Comment: @gabrielbelini, eu dei a [dica de sintaxe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) do seu código para Python. Por algum motivo, o highlght identificou a divisão inteira como comentário, o que me deixou confuso ao ler sua resposta a primeira vez

Comment: Estou obtendo o seguinte erro: **UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x8b' in position 15: character maps to <undefined>**. Estou abrindo o arquivo xlsx assim: `file = open('Resultado_17_03_2017_BR2_02_2017_VINHO.xlsx', 'r', encoding='latin1')`. Já tentei com utf-8 e o erro persistiu!!!

Comment: Tente abrir com rb ou rb+ e mantenha o encoding em utf-8

Comment: Seu problema agora é com tipos de arquivo, o python por padrão lê arquivos .txt. Se o tipo de arquivo que deseja abrir for .csv ou .xlsx pe bem provavel q irá precisar importar uma biblioteca leitora desse tipo de arquivo. De uma olhada na biblioteca OpenPyXL e nesse link aqui ensina como trabalhar com arquivos xlsx, muito simples também. https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/optimized.html

Comment: com rb e rb+ ocorre isso: **ValueError: binary mode doesn't take an encoding argument**. Vou ver a biblioteca que vc comentou!

Comment: Deu certo a luta contra o encoding?

Comment: Não tem a ver com encoding - esse código vai funcionar só pra CSV, como comentado acima. Arquivos XLSX são zipados, e se você abrir o zip, o conteúdo das linhas está numa estrutura complexa de XML. Se não puder converter a planilha para .csv para fazer a divisão, terá que instalar um módulo no Python para poder ler e escrever xlsx.  Recomendo o rows: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rows

Comment: @Bene - aproṕósito, se a solução não funcionou pra você (estou assumindo que não, por que você ainda está brigando com o "xlsx" achando que é só "encoding" - não marque a reposta como "aceita". Hoje a tarde, eu estava com tempo, vi essa questão, e pensei "bom, já tem resposta aceita, nem vou olhar). Se gostou de como está ficando, tudo bem dar "upvote", mas só aceite quando resolver o problema.

Comment: Opa, realmente ainda não deu certo a questão do encoding. Mas vou transformar em CSV e testar então. Obrigado

Answer (score 3):

> **Observação**: essa pergunta tem como objetivo uma resposta em Python, mas creio que essa resposta em `bash` possa trazer novos ares e, também, serve como curiosidade

Para fazer um tratamento textual adequado em `bash`, estou assumindo que a planilha foi exportada no para o formato [CSV](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), onde cada linha da planilha termina com um `\n` no arquivo CSV.

A ideia é jogar um conjunto de linhas em arquivos distintos. Começando a contar da linha 0, o arquivo terminará na linha 4999. Assim, as linhas 0-789 ficaraim no primeiro arquivo, 790-1579 ficariam no segundo arquivo e assim por diante. Para identificar de qual arquivo a linha `n` pertence, basta fazer a divisão inteira e somar 1: `(n / 790) + 1`.

Então, vamos lá. Iremos ler do arquivo `planilhao.csv` e jogar nos arquivos `planilhinha-I.csv`, onde `I` é o índice do arquivo. Como dito anteriormente, a linha `n` entra no arquivo com índice `I = (n / 790) + 1`. Dadas as direções gerais da estratégia a ser seguida, vamos à construção do script.

A primeira parte da estratégia é identificar, para cada linha, qual seu número. O seguinte script faz essa leitura/atribuição de número:

```bash
# o número da linha é um inteiro
declare -i line_no=0

while read LINHA; do
    # esse echo aqui é só para demonstrar a associação entre a linha lida e o line_no
    echo "linha $line_no, conteúdo ($LINHA)"

    # incremento o número da linha
    line_no+=1
done
```

Para demonstrar o cálculo de `I`, considerando `n_lines` a quantidade de linhas máxima por arquivo:

```bash
# o número da linha é um inteiro
declare -i line_no=0

# número máximo de linhas por arquivo
n_lines=790

while read LINHA; do
    # cálculo do índice do arquivo
    index=$(( (line_no / n_lines) + 1 ))

    # esse echo aqui é só para demonstrar a associação entre o line_no e o index
    echo "linha $line_no, arquivo índice $index, conteúdo ($LINHA)"

    # incremento o número da linha
    line_no+=1
done
```

Então, sabendo o índice em que vai cada linha, podemos jogar a linha para o arquivo adequado:

```bash
# o número da linha é um inteiro
declare -i line_no=0

# número máximo de linhas por arquivo
n_lines=790

# prefixo do nome do arquivo
file_prefix=planilhinha

while read LINHA; do
    # cálculo do índice do arquivo
    index=$(( (line_no / n_lines) + 1 ))

    # nome do arquivo
    file_name="${file_prefix}-${index}.csv"

    # anexa a linha ao arqvuio 
    echo "$LINHA" >> "$file_name"

    # incremento o número da linha
    line_no+=1
done
```

Então, pronto. Coloque esse script num arquivo (`separador_planilha.sh` por exemplo) e envie para ele o arquivo que você deseja separar. O comando ficaria assim:

```bash
./separador_planilha.sh < planilhao.csv
```